# Readonly View for 10 Django Class Based Views

Tags: django, django-forms, readonly

I have 10 Django Class Based Views and I want to display them read-only to the user.

I want the whole form to be read-only, not only some values. Submitting the form should be disabled on the client (HTML) and a second time on the server (POST not allowed).

Is there a MixIn or an other **simple** solution?

Comment: This may sound silly but if the forms are not editable, then why render them as forms? Why not just render regular non-editable HTML?

Comment: @solarissmoke I want to avoid doing the same thing twice. I want to render the data. I don't care if it gets rendered as form or in a different way. The layout was already done for the form. That's why I want to reuse it. I care for the goal, and I want to take the most simple strategy to get there :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a mixin that does two simple things:

- Sets html attributes for all fields in form for `disabled` and`readonly`.
- Overrides the `form_valid` method of your CBV so that no model saving ever happens; instead, the template is rendered (just as if there was no submitted data). The user, this way, does not cause any action if they submitted the form.

Form field errors may appear next to disabled fields if you are rendering the full form in your template; solve this by either erasing the form's error dictionary or by rendering each field individually without errors.

```
from django.views.generic.edit import FormMixin, ModelFormMixin

class ReadOnlyModelFormMixin(ModelFormMixin):

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):

        form = super(ReadOnlyModelFormMixin, self).get_form()

        for field in form.fields:
            # Set html attributes as needed for all fields
            form.fields[field].widget.attrs['readonly'] = 'readonly'          
            form.fields[field].widget.attrs['disabled'] = 'disabled'

        return form

    def form_valid(self, form): 
        """
        Called when form is submitted and form.is_valid()
        """
        return self.form_invalid(form)
```

Extending this concept for a non-model FormView is pretty simple; inherit from class FormMixin instead. :)

Comment: Does this work for all kinds of Django Fields and Widgets?

Comment: The 'readonly' and 'disabled' attributes are html attributes that the client can override, but prevent input events on the elements (as seen [here](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_INPUT_DISABLED.html)). The **form_valid** method is the action that happens whenever a GET or POST is made for the form/modelform defined in your CBV. By returning the **form_invalid** method whenever the form is actually valid, there is no 'valid submission' action ever taken, keeping the user from being able to make changes by submitting any forms. So, in summary, yes :)

Answer (score 1):

To disallow `POST` requests in general for class-based views you could use the following mixin:

```
class DisallowPostMixin(object):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.http_method_not_allowed(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
```

If you also want to disable certain form fields etc. you could add the `get_form` method from Ian Price's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can hack it through middleware. On request - check view name and request method (if post - redirect), on response - add input attrs in response.content. But mixin - best solution.